# Conjugate gradient with directions other than gradient

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve a nonlinear unconstrained optimization problem (minimization sense) using conjugate gradient. Suppose that, I have a direction $\bar{\nabla_f}$ better than (or equal to) gradient $\nabla_f$ direction, in the sense, that moving along the negative of their directions for some $\Delta > 0$ distance, we get better function value reduction. Can we somehow take advantage of this information to create a new version of conjugate gradient as traditional conjugate gradient only needs earlier direction and gradient information ? I am not worried about time or memory storage but less number of function evaluations.

Comment: If the new gradient is equivalent to the scaling of the gradient with a symmetric positive definite matrix, then you can use that matrix as a preconditioner in preconditioned conjugate gradient. This amounts to doing conjugate gradient in an alternative inner product. If the new gradient arises in a different manner, then it probably won't work.

Comment: If such a symmetric positive definite matrix $M$ is indeed available, how to use it as preconditioner ? For e.g.  Polak Ribiere Polyak conjugate gradient uses three steps: 1.) $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha_k d_k$ 2.) $d_{k+1}=-g_{k+1}+\beta_k d_k$ and 3.) $\beta_k=\frac{g^T_{k+1}(g_{k+1}-g_k)}{\|g_k\|^2}$ where $\alpha_k$ is steplength, $d_k$ is direction of line search and $g_k$ is gradient at $k^{th}$ step. $\beta_k$ is CG update parameter. Now how exactly I use the matrix $M$ to write new algorithm.